# TypeScript: Assignment operator inside the constructor's parameter list?

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been learning angular and typescript. While reading about dynamic forms from the https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form, I came across this piece of code

```
constructor(options: {} = {}) {
  }
```

What is the use of assigning this empty object to the options? Isn't arguments passed into the options  parameter while constructor is invoked?

Comment: if you did't pass any argument it well take the `empty object {}` by default

Comment: @YashRami wouldn't it be undefined?

Comment: nope because we are declare that `options` is a object and assign the empty object to `options` if we are getting the options `null` or `undefined`

Comment: @YashRami Ok, So its just a default value to avoid `undefined` as the default value?

Comment: yeah it is used for to assign the default value

Answer (score 0):

looks to be unnecessary to me. constructor(options: {}) would give you the same thing.